# Django admin login not showing OTP Device

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I tried adding the `otp_totp` plugin.
and pip install the requirements but still not getting anywhere.
I have added different creating a models.py file and an admin.py file still not helping.
This is my settings.py file

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_otp',
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_totp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django_otp.middleware.OTPMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

The urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django_otp.admin import OTPAdminSite
from django_otp.admin import OTPAdminSite


admin.site.__class__ = OTPAdminSite

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    
]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwFQ6.png)
```